# Mysql sign in was not working on my Local WAMP server(phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, wamp, wampserver

So first of all I'd like to say I have very little knowledge about how servers work and how mysql databases are actually used on a windows computer. I just have some basic knowledge about database and how to use some sql queries. Also I think I have resolved this issue, but I am confused about what actually happened

**The problem:**
I downloaded a local WAMP server for my web programming class and I was able to login to the mysql with phpMyAdmin at first. But for whatever reason now this would happen everytime:[image]

After reading through various threads and trying a few things I came to this solution(though none of those threads had this exact solution shown and explained well):

1. I go to search and type in run
2. I type in services.msc and run it
3. I find "MySQL80" and see that it is running. So I right click it and click "Stop"
4. go to wampserver icon in taskbar and click restart all services
5. go back to login screen for phpMyadmin and the login works now

So my guess as to what is wrong:
A few semesters ago I downloaded mysqlworkbench and used it for a different class. According to the services.msc when I click properties on "MySQL80" it shows path to executable "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe". My wampserver is located "C:\Wamp64" so maybe there are 2 different databases on my computer trying to use the same port (3306?) and since the "MySQL80" service runs automatically, it prevents the wamp from signing in? I found that setting the "MySQL80" to disabled instead of automatic allows me to sign into wamp mysql when restarting my computer without doing those steps

Can anyone clarify what was actually happening? Will I now not be able to use mysqlworkbench until I start the service again? should I get rid of that service "MySQL80"?
Thank you

Comment: Given the evidence you provide, your theory seems plausible to me.  I'd say MySQL80 is listening on port 3306 , thus wamp cannot start its own mysql server there (you should be able to corroborate this with an error from wamp's mysql) .  PHPMyAdmin connects to whatever's listening on the contested port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific error message you're seeing when trying to log in through phpMyAdmin means that your PHP version is not compatible with the new authentication method used by your MySQL server. I believe MySQL made the change with version 8.0.11, but most documentation says it was applied start with MySQL version 8.0. To access a MySQL version newer than that, you must use a PHP version 7.4 or newer.

However, your assessment is correct; based on the paths you have two MySQL versions running on the same system, which will cause conflicts. WAMP comes with its own MySQL (in `C:\Wamp64`), and you also have installed MySQL on your own (to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`). At best, you should select one to disable from starting automatically, but the best solution is to remove one (you should, of course, first export any existing data as a .sql file so you can import it to the one you leave behind). Since you're using WAMP, I would suggest removing the official standalone MySQL 8.0, because otherwise you'll have to spin up your own webserver and PHP instances to replace what you remove with WAMP.

You're certainly *able to* turn each one on or off manually or run them on different ports so that they'll both start at the same time, but I don't see that you need such complexity on your system.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I mentioned the other is from when I was using MySQL Workbench. Can I remove this server(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0) but keep the MySQL Workbench software and then have the MySQL Workbench use the wamp's database? I figure I might end up wanting to use the workbench application in the future.

Comment: The installations of MySQL Workbench and the MySQL server are in all likelihood not directly related to each other; you probably manually installed them both at the same time, but the installers should be independent from each other and Workbench will work just fine with any other MySQL server you configure for it. So yes, you should be able to remove your existing MySQL server without removing Workbench, and then configure Workbench to access the WAMP database. Make sure you back up any existing data from your current MySQL server before removing it, by exporting to an SQL file.

Comment: I ended up keeping the wamp mysql server and getting rid of the other. And my workbench is now connected to the wamp one